# jQuery Load Progress Bar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress-bar, jquery-events

I'm sure this question HAS to have been asked, but after searching through the 'Related Questions' here as well as several Google searches... I have come up empty.

I'm simply trying to implement a true bytes_loaded/bytes_total type of progress bar in jQuery or even traditional Js.  This was so easy in the AS3 days :)  ...but of course Flash comes with it's drawbacks.  All I really need to know is how to calculate the current bytes loaded and bytes total during any download.  Calculating the uploaded bytes would be sweet too.  Anyone have another posted question to direct me to?  Or have knowledge of the subject?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing for a long time, so I don't really have a solution for you. However, the guys at Plupload seem to have something similar implemented and it might help looking through their source code, http://plupload.com/example_jquery_ui.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Q/A on [progress bars for long process reporting on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732087/update-jquery-progressbar-with-json-response-in-an-ajax-request). Also check out [how to get AJAX download progress in every browser but IE](http://markmail.org/message/kmrpk7w3h56tidxs#query:jquery%20ajax%20download%20progress+page:1+mid:kmrpk7w3h56tidxs+state:results).

Comment: Dawson, thanks for your responses!  But unless i'm reading them wrong, the first seems to be working with the 4 ready states of the request, rather than the actual bytes-loaded of the item being downloaded.

the second seemed to show more promise, but I'm having trouble getting anything to actually work.  I don't have any XML script to test with, so I simply took the 'datatype' declaration out and tried to load an image...which is one of the things i'd like to load with this...but all to no avail...thoughts?

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? And a jsbin or similar might help us do this more interactively.

Comment: Ok, I tried to post this to jsbin and jsfiddle, but it wouldn't work for some reason.  Maybe I'm the problem :)  Anyway...it's posted to my server and you can view the source or even download it: http://d2burke.com/exp/progress/


I'm able to get the image size begin downloaded...but not the bytes loaded as they're being loaded..help?

Additionally...you can see what i'm trying to accomplish at:  http://d2burke.com/dev/d2v6/
Currently I just have a bar animate across the screen...doesn't actually do anything, but of course i want it to. I'd like to show the progress as the large BG image loads

Comment: Ok...so i think i'm close: http://d2burke.com/exp/progress/

Problem is...it seems to only return a partial percentage...and it's irregular at that.  Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like Firefox is choking because jqxhr.response is undefined. Try doing this to get around that: (jqxhr.response || jqxhr.responseText).length

Comment: yes!  well, that fixed it for FF and Safari...IE seems to be the hold up..then we'll have something we can share :)

Answer (score 1):

There are frameworks/plugins for this available: 
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/ 
http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/ 
and so on...

Comment: Thanks jbehren...but these are only uploader...and plugins no less, when what I think I'd rather see is what methods or functions can actually calculate the values for bytes_loaded up or down so that I can begin to develop actions for these different events from scratch.